# Dockerfile client and server build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Quick question regarding Dockerfile.

I've got a folder structure like so:

```
docker-compose.yml
  client
  src
  package.json
  Dockerfile
  ...etc
```

Client folder contains reactjs application and root is nodejs server with typescript. I've created Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /server/node_modules && chown -R node:node /server
WORKDIR /server
USER node
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . ./dist

RUN npm run build-application

COPY /src/views ./dist/src/views
COPY /src/public ./dist/src/public

EXPOSE 4000
CMD node dist/src/index.js
```

npm run build-application command executes client build (npm run build --prefix ./client) and server(rimraf dist && mkdir dist && tsc -p .). The problem is that Docker cannot find client folder error:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/server/client/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Can someone explain why? And how to fix this?

Docker compose file:

```
...
server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: mazosios-pedutes-server
    container_name: mazosios-pedutes-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

Comment: The `COPY` command in the middle of the Dockerfile puts all of the content from the host directory in a `dist` subdirectory; so you have `/server/package.json` but `/server/dist/client/...`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is saying that there is no `client/package.json` in `/server` my question is the following one.

Is your `./client` directory located within `/server`?

Dockerfile WORKDIR instruction makes all commands that follow it to be executed within the directory that you pass to WORKDIR as parameter.

I guess if you add `RUN tree -d` (lists only nested directories) after the last `COPY` instruction, you will be able to see where your `client` directory is located and you will be able to fix the path to it.